# SVN Revision Graph

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

Is there any (free) tool available that is able to produce a graph showing merges (on top of branch/tags).

I understand the difficulty associated with that and the misleading informations that can result but I would still like to have an idea of the merges (visually) in a given repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** Just came across this tool - [SVN Mapper](http://svnmapper.tigris.org/)

Haven't used it yet, but the screenshot looks promising!

---

TortoiseSVN has a pretty functional Revision Graph facility, if you can use it ( as per the comment, yeah,TSVN doesn't show merge information in the revision graph, but it is in the list for 1.7 )

Comment: Tortoise SVN does show the branch/tag creation, but it doesn't show merges.

Comment: @Benoittr - I have updated my answer. Thanks to you, I have found a new tool :)

Comment: Sources for SVN Mapper havent changed in 4 years and it is now throwing an exception when I try to hook it up to my repository. So I guess I'll look elsewhere for the moment.

Comment: where do you see the addition to the revision graph for 1.7? I am unable to find that information anywhere. I'd probably just wait until then to satisfy my curiosity.